# JSP can not read CSS because of web.xml

Tags: css, jsp

This is not a theory. I have proof. I've been on this problem for almost a day. My jsp seem to can't read/find CSS. I've done a lot of solutions but nothing work. Until I decide maybe one of my files is causing it. Then I do trial and error. Deleting file to see which one causes it.

Until i'm in web.xml. I deleted web.xml, run the JSP and boom it read the CSS. I copy back the web.xml and then again my css can't be read.

By the way i'm using spring mvc, and my project is maven web application.

below are my codes:

jsp(css link part):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/logincss.css">
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30 
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DpServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DpServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I think the error is that when i'm requesting a css file, the request goes to dispatcherservlet so that is so error. How can I fix my problem? Please I need solution i've been on this problem for over a DAY! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if you use Spring, you need to configure it to handle static resource( css,js,images etc.).  You can do it in the `DpServlet-servlet.xml` with `<mvc:resource` tag.

Comment: How exactly? Can you give me the actual line of code? If I will saves the css under "Web Pages" along side of "WEB-INF"? If I want to save it under some folders too. Lets say Web Pages -> view -> css -> mycss.css. What should be the actual code in DpServlet xml?

Comment: `<mvc:resources mapping="/view/**" location="/view/" />` and link `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/css/logincss.css"`

Comment: No luck. My css still does not load. Can you please tell me your social media account so we can chat about this? I badly needed help on this. Im on this problem for 2 days now and I cant continue to progress on my project.

Comment: please add DpServlet-servlet.xml in your answer.

Comment: Thanks men I got it worked. At last after 3 days of finding the solutions. I now understand it. Thanks again.